# boost regex pattern for special characters

Tags: c++, regex, boost

Does anyone know how to make boost pattern for special characters in c++ ?

That means not only `("[A-Za-z0-9 \\s]*")`

but `_ + - \ ) \\ ( . | ]` etc. as well so for example string like this:

`"hello world \\has (special.characters) + defined_with[boost]"` is valid

but

`"!hello world \\has (special.characters) + defined_with[boost]"` is not valid

to be more specific, something like this:

```
string input;

getline(cin,input);

boost::regex pattern1 ("[a-zA-Z0-9 \\s \\_ \\+ \\- \\\ \\) \\\\ \\( \\. \\| ]*");

if (!regex_match (input, pattern1))
    {
    cout << "invalid input" << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << input << " - is valid" << endl;
```

---

I will appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: Add them to the list, but escape them with a backslash. I don't know off hand if there's a character group for "special characters", but I don't think so.

Comment: The question is very unclear. Can you post an example of one of these regexes you'd want to use?

Comment: Are you sure you need all those space characters in the regex? (I know the answer already)

Comment: yeah i didn't need these space characters you are right. I just wasn't sure what will happen if there is no space character between "\\\ and \\\\".

Comment: i would recommend to do a set excluding the character that won't pass like that for example :  [^\\!\\?]+ , then test if match !

Comment: looks like it works fine now. So the last question is: is it possible it could throw any exception or error if the string is too long or there are too many of these special characters, etc. ?

Comment: You probably do not mean `\\\ `. You don't escape spaces in C++.

Comment: Yup, both methods      [^\\!\\?]+ and     [a-zA-Z0-9 \\s\\_\\+\\-\\\\\)\\\\\\(\\.\\|]* work well. I think that's all i needed to know. Thank you for your quick response and help.

Comment: By the way. I'll probably stick to the first one as it's better formatted. :)

Comment: yeah, it is more elegant, i'll put it as an answer so you can mark it as answered...

Comment: Can you use raw string literals from C++11? This will assist you in escaping properly.

Comment: yes I can, thanks phresnel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to do a set excluding the character that won't pass like that for example :

`[^\\!\\?]+` , then test if match

Comment: I'll go along with this solution for now, thanks again Romain.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt use Boost:regex so far, but i know a bit about Regex. 
I assume you want to match only if at least one "special character" is present.
Furthermore i assume you want only alphanummeric letters to be valid and the rest to be invalid.
Like "Good String" and "\Bad.String)". Please try to be more specific about this.

First of all matching only one class with zero or more "*" will always return true, as far as i know. Try "+" instead to match only if you have at least one instance of your class.

Second, you may try to use a class like [^a-zA-Z0-9 ] which results true if there is anything thats NOT within your class.

For further reading i suggest the documentation(yeah i know, that regex syntax is quite the hell): http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html
or my favorite for the regex syntax
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for providing me with more info Philipp. The documentation is very useful to me as well.